# Launching a Wii game on USBLoaderGX takes me back to the Homebrew Channel. How can I fix this?

Tags: nintendo-wii, homebrew

I'm new to softmodding. I have a 2011-era black Wii running Wii system menu version 4.3U. I have the latest version of both the Homebrew Channel and USB loader GX. I had heard that Wiimfi was built into USB Loader GX so I decided to connect my Wii to the internet. When I did so it asked me if I wanted to run a software update. Mostly for kicks I decided to run it since I know the wii no longer receives software updates. Big mistake. Ever since then, USB loader GX (before it launches) tells me that, since I'm running ios53, some Wii disk based games and some channels won't work. I can say now that that is true.

After about a month of researching and looking on all sorts of forums I have successfully only confused myself more. I have no idea what's going on or how to fix it, although I can tell you what I've tried:

I've tried formatting/reseting:

- The USB Drive
- The internal SD card
- The Wii itself (I know that just erases miis and stuff like that but I was desperate at that point)

I've also tried two different USB drives and SD cards, as well as reinstalling both USB loader GX and the Homebrew channel. I have also re-downloaded both of them from their respective sites. I also re-copied the ROMs (of course using WiiBackupManager) to the USB drive. Does anybody know how to fix this or at least offer some help?

P.S. Like I said before this is my first question on any stack exchange site, but I've heard these sites can be pretty competitive. So I'm just letting you know, and apologizing in advance if this question sucks.

Let me know if I missed any details and I'll fill you in.

Answer (score 1):

> When I did so it asked me if I wanted to run a software update. Mostly for kicks I decided to run it since I know the wii no longer receives software updates.

You nuked your cIOSes. The Wii detects that the IOSes you have installed do not match the current version and wanted to "update". Just reinstall your cIOSes with your application of choice and don't update again.

Comment: I completely forgot about this question, but I was actually able to fix it! I guess the guide I followed for homebrewing wasn't good, so when I went back and rehomebrewed it about 8 months ago I followed a different guide and it now works fine!

Comment: I thought you only had to install 1 IOS, do I have to install them all?